# Rhino mocks for accessing database

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, rhino-mocks

Please excuse me if this question has been asked before. 
I'm in a stage that searching for example is returning too much results that confusing me.

I'm new to Rhino mocks, i know there are tons of examples but the Interface - virtual recommendation kind of confusing me.

If my classes works fine (but i'm obliged to unit test each line of code) do i have to adapt my code to satisfy unit Testing? or should it be the other way around?

To get to the point, i have the following class and i would like to mock it.

```
public class DatabaseOperation
{
    public IList<T> GetRecords<T>(string connectionString, string storedProcedureName)
    {
        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();
            using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
            {
                command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                command.CommandText = storedProcedureName;
                var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                var fillSelection = new FillSelection<T>();
                return fillSelection.GetSelection(reader);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How can i do that?

Comment: You have to draw a line somewhere where you stop unit testing. Personally I'd be inclined to treat standard boilerplate code such as above as not requiring testing. If you have to 'test' it you'll need to mock up SQLConnection and inject it into this code, so you can test how your code interacts with it.  But I think this would be a waste of time. The more important question is how do you know the SP does what it should.

Comment: The problem is that the code is monitored with Code quality control and for none technical users, the results of this tool is the only reference. if i don't unit test all codes then the quality indicator will be in red. So i have to test it. (this is one part of many other code that interact with the database, so i was hoping to have a solution for this one and try to figure out the rest.

Comment: Then inject a Mock of SqlConnection into the code somehow.  You'll have to bend to code to make it testable - which is pointless.  But if you can't explain this to your 'customers' then you have no choice.  If I remember rightly there is a IDbConnection interface on SqlConnection which is probably what you should base the Mock on.

Comment: You should revise your metric to take such situations into account, at least as far as code coverage is concerned. That would be better than unit testing the .NET framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to test the method itself, you should add an dependency into it. It means use IDbConnection instead of SqlConnection and use it as parameter instead of connection string.
Then you can mock the input parameter and test method behavior. For example if IDbConnction.Open method is called or if all methods are called in correct order.

Your method should have following signature:

```
public IList<T> GetRecords<T>(IDbConnection connection, string storedProcedureName)
```

In your test you can then use following statements:

```
IDbConnection connectionMock = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IDateTimeProvider>(IDbConnection);

// initialize mock object and your class here

yourClassInstance.GetRecords(connectionMock, yourProcedureName);

dateTimeProviderMock.AssertWasCalled(connection => connection.Open());
```

Answer (score 1):

There are always certain parts that cannot be really unit tested with a framework like rhino, you can test it with a framework like TypeMock Isolator but this one is not free.

If you want you can test this code but that will be an integration test instead an unitary one, that means that you need an real database with fake data to pass this test. That will give you 100% code coverage but you have to be aware that it can be broken not only by this part of code, but also with a problem related with the integration.

I have a few software projects with both unitary and integration automatic testing and I'm running all them with great success.

Comment: Just to add on this post, you should take a look at SpecFlow, you can write user acceptance tests which should be doing integration testing.